# Is there a way to get the API from a URL ("repository")?

Tags: api, dspace, omeka

I'm wondering how can i get a repository API , i explain a summary , im using "Dspace connector" from Omeka S and im trying to get all the comunities from a Repository , https://74.208.251.39/ , but Dspace Connector is asking me for an endpoint , an API from the site , i know that is fact from the server , but is it in a file or is a part of some code or how can i get that api ?

Comment: API is nothing more than a set of functions and definitions. It is not something you can "get" , they should have a documentation somewhere on what endpoints they made available. It's not something you can guess

Comment: So , there is no other way to know it , unless reading that documentation , thank u so much

Comment: Choosing what endpoints (URLs) a DSpace instance offers is up to the specific DSpace repository operator. So the only way to learn is to contact them and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSpace has different APIs, [but the Omeka manual specifies, it is looking for the standard Rest API](https://omeka.org/s/docs/user-manual/modules/dspaceconnector/). You should ask the operator of the DSpace repository you want to connect to, if they have the Rest API deployed and to what endpoint it is deployed to. The DSpace operator might also have restricted access to the API.

There is a [section on the DSpace Rest API in the DSpace manual](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API). If you are yourself the DSpace operator, you'll learn there how to deploy the Rest API.

Comment: I got it , but i have another problem now , i hope you could help me on this last step , is about the image below

Answer (score 0):

The repository admin shared me this image below [ Dspace Rest API ] , that it supposes that there is the endpoint , but when i use " rest " it shows me the same , Communities and collections are empty , so should i use all the specific instructions for the Endpoint? like Get / communities? , btw i tried just with " /communities " o /items"  but the same results[Dspace Rest API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HRyn.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HRyn.png)

Comment: It's best not to ask a follow-up question as an answer to your previous question ;)

Comment: But in your example [https://74.208.251.39/rest/communities](https://74.208.251.39/rest/communities) gives me a list of communities.

Comment: I don't use Omeka, but following the manual, it seems enough to enter just the site's URL and `rest` as endpoint.